# Is there a way to distinguish between real loadable modules and modules compiled into the kernel?

Tags: freebsd, kernel-modules

When looking at FreeBSD `/boot/kernel` and `/boot/modules`, is there a way to determine which is which w/o trying to load them? Because if one tries to load a module compiled in, then `kldload` responds with "already loaded" which is not always accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get a list of the modules currently loaded using [`kldstat`(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?kldstat(8)). For example:

```
Id Refs Address                Size Name
 1   58 0xffffffff80200000   fbee78 kernel
 2    1 0xffffffff81400000   3f3128 zfs.ko
 3    1 0xffffffff81310000    e6dd0 nvidia-modeset.ko
 4    1 0xffffffff81800000   db7e30 nvidia.ko
 5    2 0xffffffff825b8000    2ec10 linux.ko
 6    6 0xffffffff817f4000     add8 linux_common.ko
 7    1 0xffffffff813f7000     3378 acpi_wmi.ko
 8    1 0xffffffff813fb000     3320 usbhid.ko
 9    1 0xffffffff825e7000     31f8 hidbus.ko
10    1 0xffffffff825eb000     32c0 wmt.ko
11    1 0xffffffff825ef000    2ae90 linux64.ko
12    1 0xffffffff8261a000     2260 pty.ko
13    1 0xffffffff8261d000     73b0 linprocfs.ko
14    1 0xffffffff82625000     3284 linsysfs.ko
15    1 0xffffffff82629000     3530 fdescfs.ko
```

Normally, the output is like above, which should be sufficient. However, with the `-v` switch the utility will give the *full path* to each module's object file (`.ko`), which you can use to better ascertain, which exact file was loaded:

```
...
15    1 0xffffffff82629000     3530 fdescfs.ko (/boot/kernel/fdescfs.ko)
        Contains modules:
                 Id Name
                253 fdescfs
```